# Hover div affects multiple divs but not siblings, child or parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover, onhover

I have found many similar posts; however, none show the same issue as mine and thus the suggested scripts are not working. 
Here's the page layout:

```
    <div id="div_block-7-3587" class="ct-div-block">
        <h2 id="headline-8-3587" class="ct-headline">Great Tires Live Here</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div_block-14-3587" class="ct-div-block">
        <h2 id="headline-15-3587" class="ct-headline">All-day, Everyday, Durability</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div_block-16-3587" class="ct-div-block">
        <h2 id="headline-17-3587" class="ct-headline">Bringing Joy to the Outdoors</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div_block-19-3587" class="ct-div-block">
        <h2 id="headline-20-3587" class="ct-headline">More Than Just Hitting Balls</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div_block-22-3587" class="ct-div-block">
        <h2 id="headline-23-3587" class="ct-headline">Options for Every Need</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div_block-25-3587" class="ct-div-block">
        <h2 id="headline-26-3587" class="ct-headline">Expanding Human Powered Transportation</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="new_columns-73-3587" class="ct-new-columns">
        <a id="div_block-50-3587" class="ct-link" href="./product-category/automotive/" target="_self">
            <img id="image-54-3587" alt="hover swap passenger tire image" src="./Hover Swap Test Page - DURO Tires_files/DTire_Hover_Auto.png" class="ct-image">
            <h3 id="headline-55-3587" class="ct-headline">Automotive</h3>
        </a>
        <a id="div_block-66-3587" class="ct-link" href="./product-category/powersports/" target="_self">
            <img id="image-67-3587" alt="hover swap Psports tire image" src="./Hover Swap Test Page - DURO Tires_files/DTire_Hover_Psport.png" class="ct-image">
            <h3 id="headline-68-3587" class="ct-headline">Powersports<br></h3>
        </a>
        <a id="div_block-63-3587" class="ct-link" href="./product-category/golf-and-light-utility/" target="_self">
            <img id="image-64-3587" alt="hover swap golf category tire image" src="./Hover Swap Test Page - DURO Tires_files/DTire_Hover_Golf.png" class="ct-image">
            <h3 id="headline-65-3587" class="ct-headline">Golf and Light Utility</h3>
        </a>
        <a id="div_block-60-3587" class="ct-link" href="./product-category/specialty/" target="_self">
            <img id="image-61-3587" alt="hover swap specialty tire image" src="./Hover Swap Test Page - DURO Tires_files/DTire_Hover_Spec.png" class="ct-image">
            <h3 id="headline-62-3587" class="ct-headline">Specialty</h3>
        </a>
        <a id="div_block-57-3587" class="ct-link" href="./tires/bicycle-tires/" target="_self">
            <img id="image-58-3587" alt="hover swap bicycle tire image" src="./Hover Swap Test Page - DURO Tires_files/DTire_Hover_Bike.png" class="ct-image">
            <h3 id="headline-59-3587" class="ct-headline">Bicycle</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is broken down into two sections:
1. The first section are div blocks that contain a background image and some text.
     Only the first div block is visible. The rest are display:none.
2. The second section is a row of links with each one containing an images and text.

The goal: Hovering over one  div (tire image) hides the a shown hero image div and replaces it with a corresponding hidden hero image div.
For example: Hover over  id="div_block-50-3587" causes div_block-7-3587 to change to display:none and causes div_block-14-3587 to be visible.

I have tried CSS only which won't work unless I switch these so the links are before the hero image. This is a pain as it affects the responsive layout. Thus I would prefer a script option. However, all of my attempts, including this one have not been successful.

```
        $(function(){
   $("#div_block-50-3587").hover(
        function(){
            $("#div_block-7-3587").css('display','none');
            $("#div_block-14-3587").css('display','block');
        },
        function(){
            $("#div_block-7-3587").css('display','block');
            $("#div_block-14-3587").css('display','none');
        }
    );
});
```

Thus I come to you in search of suggested direction.

Comment: Now I'm on mobile phone. You could remove first $ and its paranthes. And try again.

Comment: Thanks, Huso. I think I found the issue. I had forgotten to call for js. Adding this allowed it to start working. <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script> The swap now works; however, it caused the hero image to change sizes and causes a width glitch.

Comment: I'm glad you found the mistake. You are welcome.

Comment: And the repair for the glitch in CSS was fixed by swapping 'block' for 'flex'.